# What is the best way to design background jobs in microservices architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am using microservices architecture. As per my requirements, there are some Restful services required and some background jobs to be developed.

For an example of Groceries delivery system,

- Customers service - some restful service
- Provider service - some restful service
- OrderProvision - some background service which checks whether all of customer items got provided by different providers.

Once done, send an initiation to customer with the status and initiate delivery system to start delivering

For the case of OrderProvision what is the best way to implement microservices?
In case of .Net framework, I can create a windows service/ scheduler task to run in background and do the checks. If it needs to be deployed on other servers like Linux, it does not work. What would be the best way to code such background tasks in microservices architecture?

Comment: Take a look at the concept of [Sagas](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/) in NServiceBus

Answer (score 1):

You can use task queues. Take a look at following article. Although it is for python, concepts can be adopted for other languages.

https://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage a Universal Controller / Universal Agent architecture which will let you plan and deploy containers at scale relative to your requirements.

Windows task scheduler will not help you with cross-platform background code checks. You will need an agnostic agent that can communicate across all systems and report back to a central location (the controller).

Here is a quick video on job scheduling solutions and on microservices orchestration:

[Stonebranch - Job Scheduling](https://www.stonebranch.com/solutions/enterprise-job-scheduling/)

[Stonebranch - Microservices](https://www.stonebranch.com/solutions/cloud-automation/)

Full disclosure, I am an engineer at Stonebranch